# Get exact milliseconds from time stamp - Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a time stamp column in data frame (scala) and would like to get milliseconds from it. unix_timestamp is chopping of till seconds, I can't do unix_timestamp*1000 because I am looking for exact milliseconds conversion

Input dataframe

```
+---------+-----------------------+-----+-----------------------+
|OrderName|DateTime               |Count|timestamp              |
+---------+-----------------------+-----+-----------------------+
|a        |2020-07-11 23:58:45.538|1    |2020-07-11 23:58:45.538|
|a        |2020-07-12 00:00:07.307|2    |2020-07-12 00:00:07.307|
|a        |2020-07-12 00:01:08.817|3    |2020-07-12 00:01:08.817|
|a        |2020-07-12 00:02:15.675|1    |2020-07-12 00:02:15.675|
|a        |2020-07-12 00:05:48.277|1    |2020-07-12 00:05:48.277|
+---------+-----------------------+-----+-----------------------+

Second column is string and i used to to_timestamp($"DateTime") to get 4th column
```

```
Example 2020-07-11 23:58:45.538 -> 1594537125538
```

Comment: Are you looking for the milliseconds field of your timestamp, or are you looking for the epoch milliseconds value for your timestamp? What's your expected output?

Comment: I am looking for the milliseconds Long field, similar to TimeStamp.getTime() method in java which would accept time stamp and return milliseconds (Long)

Comment: Example - 2020-07-11 23:58:45.538 -> 1594537125538

Answer (score 1):

You can get this with a UDF that reads your string into an instant and then converts it to Epoch milliseconds:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import java.time._
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

//...

spark.udf.register("to_epoch_millis", 
                   (s: String) => LocalDateTime.parse(s, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"))
                       .toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli())
```

Then

```
df.selectExpr("to_epoch_millis(DateTime) as ts").show()
```

```
+-------------+
|           ts|
+-------------+
|1594511925538|
|1594512007307|
+-------------+
```

The above assumes `DateTime` is a UTC timestamp.